# References about Morita equivalent.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I have known that two k-algebras $A$ and $B$ are said to be Morita equivalent if the categories Mod A and Mod B are equivalent. But I'm not familar with ways to construct a Morita equivalence between algebras. So who can provide me some references or papers about some ways to get or construct Morita equivalences?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence#Criteria_for_equivalence) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "Frobenius algebras I" by Skowronski and Yamagata has a chapter about Morita equivalence and also the new representation theory book by Zimmermann gives many details.